# sqlite3 (node js) - how to see if you are on last row in db.each

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am trying to see if i am on the last row when using `db.each`

```
accountDb.each("SELECT * FROM account", (err, row) => {
// how do i see if row is last?
}
```

I am not sure if there is a function to check, or a variable or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all` to return all rows and then use a `for` loop:

```
accountDb.all("SELECT * FROM account", (err, rows) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const numRows = rows.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        if (i === numRows - 1) {
            // Last row...
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

check row is null or empty?Sorry, I don't know much about nodejs api ^_^

Comment: No, I don't think that would work, as when I log each line, it just stops at the last. An "empty" line never gets logged.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).